# Is it possible to get a full list of bonds with RDKitMinimalLib in Julia?

Tags: julia, rdkit

I am trying to use `RDKitMinimalLib` with `Julia`, and I was wondering if there was a way to get a full list of bonds as with `mol.GetBonds()` in the full `RDKit`.

The [source code](https://github.com/eloyfelix/RDKitMinimalLib.jl/blob/main/src/RDKitMinimalLib.jl) seems to indicate that there is no way. But I was wondering if there is a hack I can use--given that the full `RDKit` is not available in `Julia`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. But the information is hidden away in the output of the  `get_json` function.

Here is a simple example:

```
import RDKitMinimalLib
import JSON

# SMILES for benzene
smlbnz = "C1=CC=CC=C1"

# Benzene molecule
molbnz = RDKitMinimalLib.get_mol(smlbnz)

# CommonChem JSON
jsonbnz = JSON.parse(RDKitMinimalLib.get_json(mol))
```

Now the dictionary `jsonbnz` has a field called `"molecules"`, which contains a `Vector` of molecules. We can extract the full lists of atoms and bonds for each molecule:

```
julia> jsonbnz["molecules"][1]["atoms"]
6-element Vector{Any}:
 Dict{String, Any}("impHs" => 1)
 Dict{String, Any}("impHs" => 1)
 Dict{String, Any}("impHs" => 1)
 Dict{String, Any}("impHs" => 1)
 Dict{String, Any}("impHs" => 1)
 Dict{String, Any}("impHs" => 1)

julia> jsonbnz["molecules"][1]["bonds"]
6-element Vector{Any}:
 Dict{String, Any}("bo" => 2, "atoms" => Any[0, 1])
 Dict{String, Any}("atoms" => Any[1, 2])
 Dict{String, Any}("bo" => 2, "atoms" => Any[2, 3])
 Dict{String, Any}("atoms" => Any[3, 4])
 Dict{String, Any}("bo" => 2, "atoms" => Any[4, 5])
 Dict{String, Any}("atoms" => Any[5, 0])

julia>
```

More information about the `CommonChem` format can be found [here](https://github.com/CommonChem/CommonChem).